# How to give a value for ViewBag inside the jquery in mvc c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have following input field.

```
<input class="book_now_modal BClick" type="text" id="destinationFrom_modal" name="destinationFrom_modal" placeholder="@ViewBag.AmritsarList[0].Destination">
```

time to time I want to change the value inside the view bag.is there a way to give dynamic value to the viewbag item.I have tried with jquery as below.

```
  $(".AClick").click(function () {
            //$(".BClick").attr("placeholder"," ");
            var s = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
            var neededVAl = "@@ViewBag.AmritsarList"+"["+s+"]"+".Destination";
            alert(neededVAl);
            var b = $(".BClick");
            $(this).attr("placeholder",neededVAl);
        });
```

like this I replace the `placeholder` as an alert it gives `@ViewBag.AmritsarList[1].Destination` but it didn't change the placeholder.how can I do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var neededVAl = "@@ViewBag.AmritsarList"+"["+s+"]"+".Destination";
```

You can't access the `ViewBag` using above statement, since it accessible on server side. Your JavaScript statement is executed on the client side and can't directly access it.

However, You can use [**Json.Encode**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json.encode%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) Method converts a data object to a string that is in the JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) format.

```
var jsObject = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.AmritsarList));    
$(".AClick").click(function () {        
    var s = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
    var neededVAl = jsObject[s].Destination;
    alert(neededVAl);
    $(this).attr("placeholder",neededVAl);
});
```